# Como deixar um código em HTML rodavel em qualquer computador por Pen drive

Tags: html, css

Queria saber como programar hyperlink e IMG src dentro de um Pen drive para poder abrir em outros computadores apenas executando dentro do próprio Pen drive.

Comment: Olá João! Podes colocar o HTML  que tens e referir que problemas tens quando o usas de uma pen?

Comment: Então Sérgio meu objetivo não é um programa em si mas, eu tenho um problema que programa em casa e em uma apresentação em um computador diferente todos meus códigos estão com os caminhos de hyperlink e de imagem como padrão (c:/usuário/João/desktop) e quando passo por Pen drive nada mais funciona.

Comment: Tens de usar caminhos relativos. Se colocares na pergunta uma parte do HTML como exemplo podemos ajudar como deves mudar isso.

Comment: Clica em [edit] para adicionar informação e podemos depois ajudar a formatar.

Comment: @JoãoSimões Respondi, depois ve se funcionou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resolvendo Problema**

Você tem que usar caminho relativos, hoje você deve estar utilizando em seu link caminho semelhantes a este:

```
<script src="c:/usuário/João/desktop"></script>
```

Onde você poe todo caminho do arquivo, se você utilizar caminhos relativos:

```
 <a href="desktop/menu2.html">menu2</a>
```

Ele seguira o caminho da pagina acrescentando o restante.

**Falando um pouco mais sobre caminho Relativo  e Absoluto**

O endereço absoluto é a informação para a localização do recurso de forma independente da página atual (protocolo + domínio + caminho). O endereço relativo é a informação para a localização do recurso a partir da página atual.

absoluto:

> "http://www.nce.ufrj.br/cursos/inscricao.htm"

relativo:

```
"inscricao.htm"
```

Fonte: http://www.nce.ufrj.br/ginape/cursohtml/conteudo/ligacoes/absrel.htm

Comment: Muito obrigado Luiz. :)

Comment: funcinou? Entendeu a logica? Se sim, marca como resolvido dando o check embaixo do rate da resposta :), para mostrar para os demais usuarios que esta é a solução @JoãoSimões